# Oracle - Extract last month name from sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

If the date in my record is '04-NOV-2021', for ex, I want to show 'October'.

```
select extract(MONTH FROM add_months(sysdate,-1)) from dual;
```

That code will give me the '10' for October, but how do I format it as 'October'?

Comment: `to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'Month')`

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `to_char` with the right `nls_language`.

```
SQL>  select to_char(sysdate,'Month', 'nls_language=''english''' ) from dual ;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MONTH','NLS_LANGUAG
------------------------------------
November

SQL>
```

In your case

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1))),'Month', 'nls_language=''english''' ) from dual ;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(S
------------------------------------
October
```

Or

```
SQL> select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'fmMonth', 'nls_language="english"')  from dual ;

TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'FMMO
------------------------------------
October

SQL>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` back and forth. Just do `to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'fmMonth', 'nls_language="english"')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, thank you. I added to the answer ;)